# in more module project , i have error in androd databingding

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

Kotlin plugin is applied to the project :business_module:module_web but we cannot find the KaptTask. Make sure you apply the kotlin-kapt plugin because it is necessary to use kotlin with data binding.

Comment: Pls add an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i solve error ,

if you project have buildSrc, you can delete build.gradle ->

implementation gradleApi()
implementation localGroovy()

replease remote url